# ButterKnife 8.0.1 not working

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, butterknife

I am using `butterknife 8.0.1`, but a `nullpointerexception` is appearing.

This line is on my build.grade file: 
        `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'`

this is my `Main Class:` (I wrote the includes properly)

```
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.MainScreenTextView) TextView mainText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        **mainText.setText("Butter knife is working fine");**
    }
```

and this is `MainActivity.xml`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MainScreenTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the Main Screen"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#666666"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Per [the readme](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#download), you need to include the `butterknife-compiler` in order for the generated code to be produced automatically:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
}
```

Without this there is no generated code to be loaded and thus none of the fields get set.

You can verify ButterKnife is working by calling `ButterKnife.setDebug(true)` and looking in Logcat.

Comment: Worked well for me also. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I followed the same readme conditions but for mine its not working. its giving me this   `Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:compileWholesaleDebugJava'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for com.sme.Activity.fragment.AccountStatementFragment`

Comment: Use lowercase package names. Otherwise you'll need to wait for 8.1.0 where that bug is fixed.

Comment: Hi @JakeWharton When i add 
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

send me and error

Comment: why does the author make it so complex?

Comment: Thx, Jake. Add this info to your mainpage "download". Many people will be bless you for this.

Comment: @KaiWang because to reduce Reflection in code so to increase execution speed by 30%

Comment: @josedlujan you need to add classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4' to build.grade  file of your project not your App

Comment: Still getting `NPA`

Comment: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Comment: Just these two dependencies are required  compile'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'

Comment: gradle please should also include annotation processor dependency .I messed up just cause it gave me single dependency.

Answer (score 7):

I used this library in Fragment and has NPE. My code was:

```
ButterKnife.bind(view);
```

But it was wrong. Library need to know two objects: 
1) Target - with annotations @BindView 
2) Source - with views

It will be right to write:

```
ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
```

When this - your fragment, and view - view of this fragment.

Comment: What if it is an activity?

Answer (score 6):

for me the problem was that I was using

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
```

instead of

```
 apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0
```

Comment: what's the difference?

Answer (score 5):

```
App Level(build.gradle)

apply plugin: 'android-apt'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}


Project Level(build.gradle)

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Config Butterknife on build.gradle file like this,

```
compile("com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1")
annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1"
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you use kotlin:

make sure to use this dependency in module app:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
   kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
}
```

Comment: This was my issue. To add to this, even if you have zero kotlin code in your project but have used and then deleted Kotlin snippets, you will still run into an error unless the `kapt` line above is included.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too, just because I've added butterknife from Android Studio's Dependency management and not by copy-pasting gradle lines from Butterknife website.
So I had to add 

`compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'`

instead of just

`compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'`

Answer (score 1):

So for an update to a previous answer. If you are using `annotationProcessor` like this

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
```

change it up to this:

```
kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
```

it's `kapt` instead of `apt` as of 2023.

Answer (score 0):

From JakeWharton

> Yes that plugin is no longer needed. You're already using
>   annotationProcessor for the 'butterknife-compiler' artifact which is
>   built-in to the Android Gradle plugin.

Then the solution is delete apt classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

Answer (score 0):

Add `annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'` In your gradle file it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced this problem, after updating my project to Gradle version `3.0.1`. I was able to fix it by just including in Gradle `app` file the line:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

The final result was:

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

        ...

        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    }
```

I hope this helps somebody, although this question being old.