# How to fix Attempt to invoke virtual method while loading ads

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I'm setting up an app in android and I want to add advertisements in the app. I followed all the documentation from:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start
and
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

But it doesn't work for me.

- I already tried making a new project and doing it all over again.
- I tried to follow some youtube tutorials.
- I tried reinstalling android studio.
- I tried googling many things but nothing works for me, stuff like this

[How to solve NullPointerException void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest) with Butterknife](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401662/how-to-solve-nullpointerexception-void-com-google-android-gms-ads-adview-loadad/39417492)

This is in my activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

My MainActivity.java

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button buttonEnable;
    private ImageView imageFlashlight;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 50;
    private boolean flashLightStatus = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this,
                "ca-app-pub-3272193195027774~9744363531");

        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }
}
```

My AndroidManifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hp.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-121329314517774~9742163635"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my build.gradle (Module:app)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.1'
}
```

The error:

```
2019-06-05 12:38:40.796 23410-23410/com.example.hp.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hp.myapplication, PID: 23410
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hp.myapplication/com.example.hp.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class meta-data
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2858)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2933)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1612)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class meta-data
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class meta-data
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.meta-data" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:703)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.hp.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
2019-06-05 12:38:40.798 23410-23410/com.example.hp.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6982)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2933)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1612)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.hp.myapplication-B3wC82OnVOJBCK4nCiFXJA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:46)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:722)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:755)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:982)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5812)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1680)
                ... 6 more
```

Comment: You forgot `setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_view)` at the beginning of `onCreate` method.

Comment: I have but i left it out because I thought it wasn't relevant for this subject.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include these lines in your code:-

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

You need to inflate your xml file(your layout file) then only you can call findViewById() method to find the view associated with your layout. Since no layout has been inflate by you so android is unable to find your adView element and thus shows error then you try to perform something in it.

Comment: Doesn't work still error. When I ALT + LEFT CLICK it, it even redirects me towards the layout

Comment: Like i said you need to write super.onCreate() & setContentView() before you call findViewById() as i can see in your edited question that you have written them after you called findViewById() thefefore android is still unable to find the adView as the layout in inflated later.

Comment: Hmm yes i am sorry, youre right, but now i get this error?     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hp.myapplication/com.example.hp.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class meta-data

Comment: Could you please post your full xml file and update the error log also.

Comment: Could you try these two things:- 1) Build -> Clean project   2) File -> Invalidate cache/Restart