# error when i try to sync the gradle and trying to inject butterknife

Tags: android

I keep on running into this error when i try to sync the gradle (i am trying to inject butterknife). here is my gradle code.

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blog.dawitseyoum.sharenote"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

the error is that i cant import this when i try to work with butterknife.

```
import butterknife.Bind;
```

Comment: did you try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37013888/3678308 ???

Comment: i have updated the question now