# Incorrectly typed data found for annotation element public abstract int[] butterknife.OnClick.value()

Tags: android

I was following an Android tutorial; [here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541525/android-studio-3-2-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0-4818971) my previous error I faced while following the tutorial.

As I reached almost the end of the tutorial, I got the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationTypeMismatchException: Incorrectly typed data found for annotation element public abstract int[] butterknife.OnClick.value() (Found data of type int[])

I don't know what I say more about it, so I will paste the app Gradle file here:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def fileName = "${project.name}_${output.baseName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        outputFileName = new File(output.outputFile.parent, fileName).getName()
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tomsapp.mulberry"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath true
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation project(path: ':licensing')

implementation('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation('com.github.afollestad:drag-select-recyclerview:0.3.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

implementation 'com.github.afollestad:bridge:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview:0.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.afollestad:assent:0.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.afollestad:inquiry:2.0.1'

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.github.florent37:glidepalette:1.0.6@aar'

implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.apps.muzei:muzei-api:2.0'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
}
```

I referred this link for a solution, but the mentioned solutions in it created new errors in my code - [ButterKnife 8.0.1 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013619/butterknife-8-0-1-not-working)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer Okay, I will improve my questions now onwards.